# Omega limit-set is union of omega limit points

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits, dynamical-systems

Given some dynamical system $(X, \mathbb{T}, S_t)$.
Prove for any $B \subset X$ the inclusion holds; $$\bigcup_{b \in B}  \omega(B) \subset \omega(B)$$

From my understanding, it could be equivalent to prove that $\omega(\omega(B)) \subset \omega(B)$ which is obvious but difficult to formulate as a proof.

Comment: Would you define the term $\omega(B)$? I understand this notation to mean the set of limit points of the form $\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{t_n} b_n$, where $t_n \to \infty$ and $\{ b_n\} \subset B$.

Comment: Alternatively you might be working with the definition $\omega(B) = \cap_{T > 0} \overline{\cup_{t \geq T} S_t(B)}$, where $\overline{Z}$ denotes the closure of $Z$ in $X$.

Comment: We've been taught both definitions but have been advised to use the definition; Let B $/subset$ X. Then w $/in /omega$ if and only if there's sequences $t_n /rightarrow /infty$ and $x_n /in B : S_{t_n}x_n /rightarrow /omega$ as $t /rightarrow /infty$

Comment: These definitions are equivalent for complete metric spaces (perhaps with separability? it's a good exercise to check).

Answer (score 1):

Here, for a set $C \subset X$, we have
$$
\omega(C) = \{ \text{limit points of the form } \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{t_n} b_n \, , \text{ where } t_n \to \infty, \{ b_n \} \subset C\} \, .
$$

To prove
$$
\bigcup_{b \in B} \omega(b) \subset \omega(B) \, ,
$$
for any $B \subset X$, let $x \in \omega(b)$ for some $b \in B$. Then, $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{t_n} (b)$ for some sequence $t_n \to \infty$. But notice that if we define the sequence $\{b_n \} \subset B$ by setting $b_n = b$ for all $n$, then $x$ is a limit point of the desired form $x = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{t_n} b_n$. Thus $x \in \omega(B)$.

Comment: This is really about unpacking the definitions.